# How to intercept the return variable using Java Agent

Tags: java, debugging, javassist, intercept, javaagents

I am intercepting a method and in my application using Java Agent. Through the Javassist bytecode manipulation framework I could be able to

```
addLocalVariable(..); - add local variable.
insertBefore(..); - insert method at the start of the body.
insertAfter(..); - insert method at the end of the body.
```

I am using this mechanism and I encounter a problem. say this is the code I am executing

```
fun(req,res){
    interceptstart(req,res)
    .....
    ....
    logic
    ....
    ....
    ...
    ..
    if (..){
        res.add.....
        return res
        //then method in the below won't capture anything
    }
    else if(){
        res.add.....
        return res
        //then method in the below won't capture anything
    }

    ......

    interceptend(req,res)

}
```

Here I wanted to capture the request and the response. But the problem I am facing now is I could be able to capture the request because request contains all the variable but I could not be able to capture the response because response variables are added and `returned` and there's no way that the `interceptend` will be executed.

is there any way to capture the return variable by intercepting using JavaAgent and Javassist?